# Delete duplicate entries in a text file

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing

I created a txt file using two requests, one LDAP and one SQL. Results of the two requests are stored in the same txt file.

The txt file looks like this :

```
user1@domain.fr
user2@domain.fr
user3@domain.fr
user1@domain.fr
user4@domain.fr
```

Because a user can be in the two databases, I need to delete duplicate entries, using bash.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind your file ending up sorted, sort it and filter it; either

```
sort -u file
```

if your `sort` supports it, or

```
sort file | uniq
```

if not, and you'll get on standard output the sorted list of unique email addresses.

If you want to keep the addresses in the original order, use `awk`:

```
awk '!(count[$0]++)' file
```

Comment: `sort -u` doesn't report the unique line but the first in lines sort the same in current locale.

Comment: @cuonglm Indeed, but is there a case where two different email addresses would have the same collation?

Comment: @StephenKitt: `①@example.com` and `②@example.com` in `en_US.utf8` locale.

Comment: @cuonglm: `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; (echo ①@example.com; echo ②@example.com) | sort | uniq` also merges both lines, so only the `awk` solution is viable in that case.

Comment: @StephenKitt: It seems that you are using GNU uniq, it's not POSIX compliant in this case, you must use `uniq -i`.

Comment: Is it able to directly delete entries in the file and then save into it without creating new temporliy file using `awk`?

Comment: @CodyChan not directly, `awk` can't manipulate files in that way. You can combine `awk` with `sponge` (from [`moreutils`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/)) to re-write the input file.